# Why is a defined token not recognized during syntax analysis in C using Bison?

Tags: c, syntax, compiler-construction, token, lexical

I'm currently working on a simple infix-to-postfix compiler for a given grammar. I'm currently at the stage of syntax analysis. I have already written a lexical analyzer, using Flex library, however I'm stuck on a seemingly simple problem. The information below might seem like a lot to process, but I presume the problem is rather basic to anyone with some experience in compiler construction.

Here is my lexer:

```
%{

    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "global.h"
    int lineno = 1, tokenval = NONE;

%}


letter      [A-Za-z]
digit       [0-9]
id      {letter}({letter}|{digit})*

%option     noinput
%option     nounput

%%


[ \t]+      {}
\n      {lineno++;}
{digit}+    {tokenval = atoi(yytext);
        printf("digit\n");
         return NUM;}
{id}        {int p;
         p = lookup(yytext);
         if(p==0){
            p = insert(yytext, ID);
            }
         tokenval = p;
         return symtable[p].token;
        }
<<EOF>>     {return DONE;}
.       {tokenval = NONE;
         return yytext[0];}
```

Nothing special here, just defining some tokens and handling them.

And my parser.y file:

```
%{

    #include "global.h"
%}


%token digit


%%

start:  line {printf("success!\n");};

line:   expr ';' line | expr ;

expr:   digit;


%%


void yyerror(char const *s)
{
    printf("error\n");
};


int main()
{
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is on the line:

```
expr:   digit;
```

The compiler has evidently some problem with the `digit` token, since if I put instead anything constant other than a digit, it all works fine, and expressions like `-;` or `+;` will be accepted. I have no idea why is this happening, especially that I'm pretty sure my lexical analyzer works fine.

The `global.h` file is just a linkage for other files, contains necessary function prototypes and links to any necessary variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BSIZE 128
#define NONE -1
#define EOS '\0'
#define NUM 256
#define DIV 257
#define MOD 258
#define ID  259
#define DONE 260
extern int tokenval;
extern int lineno;
struct entry
{
  char *lexptr;
  int token;
};
extern struct entry symtable[];
int insert (char s[], int tok);
void error (char *m) ;
int lookup (char s[]) ;
void init () ;
void parse () ;
int yylex (void) ;
void expr () ;
void term () ;
void factor () ;
void match (int t) ;
void emit (int t, int tval) ;
void yyerror(char const *s);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scanner returns **NUM** when it has found a sequence of digits, not **digit**. The identifier **digit** is just used internally in your Flex specification.

Then you have *another* **digit** defined as a token in your Bison grammar, but it is not connected in any way to the Flex one.

To fix this, use **NUM**, both in your Bison grammar and as a return value from the lexer. Don't declare it yourself with **#define**, but let Bison create those declarations, from your **%token** definitions. You can use the **-d** flag to get Bison to output a header file. Run Bison before Flex, and **#include** Bison's output header file, with **NUM** in it, in your Flex code.

Comment: Okay, that's valuable information. So I must misunderstand the purpose of declaring tokens in my parser file. How can I tell Bison then, that an expression should be one or more digits? `[0-9]`, like in lexer.

Comment: Use **NUM**, bot in your Bison grammar and as a return value from the lexer. Don't declare it yourself with **#define**, but let Bison create those declarations, from your **%token** definitions. You can use the **-d** flag to get Bison to output a header file.

Comment: Okay. But that way lexer will not have access to `NUM`. Should I then run `bison` before `flex`?

Comment: Yes. Run Bison before Flex, and **#include** Bison's output header file, with **NUM** in it, in your Flex code.

Comment: Okay - it all works fine. Just one, final question. Since I included my `.h` file, generated by bison, in my Flex code - is it a good programming practice to include header files, that will only be generated while invoking `make`?

Comment: At least I see no reason not to include it. Generating code, and then compiling it, is nothing strange. But you need to do the build steps in the right order.

Comment: Yes, I managed to reconfigure my makefile. Thanks, you helped a lot, now I think I understand!